# binding table() and prop.table() in R

Tags: r

Please refer to example below.

```
> rbind(Freq = table(KN5FMc$LW_MT), Prop = 100*prop.table(table(KN5FMc$LW_MT)))

              1          2          8          9
Freq 8723.00000 2017.00000 2146.00000 151.000000
Prop   66.90957   15.47135   16.46084   1.158242
```

I would like Freq and Prop(rounded) row to be like:

```
              1          2          8          9
Freq 8723 2017 2146 151
Prop   66.91   15.47   16.46   1.16
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just like the other question, sample data would be very useful here

Comment: Do you want to just change how this is printed to the screen, or how it is actually stored?

Comment: @thelatemail : I would like to change how it is actually stored

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, if you would like to change how the data are actually stored, you would have to store the result as a character using your current approach. This is because your `rbind` approach stores the data as a simple matrix, so everything has to be the same type (ie, character, numeric).

If you wanted to your data to display as desired using your code, you can convert to character and use `sprintf`:

*Sample data*

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e5
KN5FMc <- data.frame(LW_MT = sample(LETTERS[1:6], n, replace = TRUE))
```

Using `rbind`

```
rbnd <- rbind(Freq = table(KN5FMc$LW_MT), 
              Prop = sprintf("%.2f", 
                             100*prop.table(table(KN5FMc$LW_MT))))

#      A       B       C       D       E       F      
# Freq "16685" "16818" "16656" "16536" "16774" "16531"
# Prop "16.68" "16.82" "16.66" "16.54" "16.77" "16.53"

class(rbnd)
# [1] "matrix" "array" 

str(rbnd)
#   chr [1:2, 1:26] "3869" "3.87" "3857" "3.86" "3769" "3.77" "3941" "3.94" "3904" "3.90" "3788" "3.79" "3829" "3.83" "3867" "3.87" "3818" "3.82" ...
#   - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "Freq" "Prop"
#   ..$ : NULL
```

Alternatively, storing your data as a data frame provides some more flexibility than as a matrix (ie, you can have different types - numbers, characters, logical, etc - in a data frame). But unfortunately all *columns* in a data frame must be the same type. If you wanted to display the data as you desired and still be able to perform mathematical operations, you would have to store your data in long format so that each column would return a different type:

```
df <- data.frame(table(KN5FMc$LW_MT), 
                 Prop = as.numeric(sprintf("%.2f", 
                                           100*prop.table(table(KN5FMc$LW_MT)))))

#        Var1     Freq  Prop
# 1         A     16685 16.68
# 2         B     16818 16.82
# 3         C     16656 16.66
# 4         D     16536 16.54
# 5         E     16774 16.77
# 6         F     16531 16.53

class(df)
# [1] "data.frame"

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Freq.Var1: Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
# $ Freq.Freq: int  16685 16818 16656 16536 16774 16531
# $ Prop     : num  16.7 16.8 16.7 16.5 16.8 ...
```